# Inverse in $p$-adics

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If I know that $x\equiv 1 \mod 16$ i.e. $x=1+a_4\cdot2^4+a_5\cdot2^5\cdots$ what can I say about its inverse $1/x$? 
Is it also $1/x \equiv 1 \mod 16$? Do I know and coefficient?

Is this good deduction:
Let $v=1/x$. Since
$$xv=1$$
and  $1\equiv 1\mod 16$ then $v=1/x\equiv 1 \mod 16$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any whole number N >= 2, the residue classes modulo N that are prime to N form a group under multiplication.  Each member of such a group has just one multiplicative inverse, which could be itself.  So 1 is the one and only inverse of 1 modulo 16.